# Hide part of a CompoundElement in a FormPage

Tags: inputfield

I have a `FormPage` I am working on that uses `CompoundElement` to structure the output.  In most cases, I want the user to be able to enter both fields, but occasionally I want to have the field hidden while providing the input automatically.

In a normal form, hiding the field but providing input is easy:

```
FormPage[{"First" -> "String", 
  "Last" -> <|"Interpreter" -> "String", "Input" -> "Jones", 
    "Hidden" -> True|>}, # &]
```

In the example above, I can enter any First Name and the Last name will return as "Jones".

However, if I use `CompoundElement` to try and reach a similar result, the field is no longer hidden:

```
FormPage[{"Name:" -> 
   CompoundElement[<|"First" -> "String", 
     "Last" -> <|"Interpreter" -> "String", "Input" -> "Jones", 
       "Hidden" -> True|>|>]}, # &]
```

[image: Form Example]

The actual form I am working on is much more complex, hence the need for `CompoundElement` but the above code isolates the problem.

I have scoured the documentation for `CompoundElement` and while it is included as an option in the `FormPage` write ups, the focus is more on structuring data in the supporting documents.  Perhaps there is an option I can use in defining the form appearance?

**UPDATE:** This quirk has been corrected in v12.0 and later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a convenient function for `Form*` (and other cloud stuff) debugging:

```
testForm[form_] :=

 With[{xml = 
    Import[Forms`GenerateHTTPResponse`PackagePrivate`handleExport[
      form], {"HTML", "XMLObject"}]},
  FirstCase[
    xml,
    XMLElement["form", _, _],
    FirstCase[
     xml,
     XMLElement["div", {___, "id" -> "content", ___}, _],
     None,
     ∞
     ],
    ∞
    ] // StringReplace[ExportString[#, "XML"], 
     Repeated["\n" ~~ (" " ..), {2, ∞}] -> "\n"] &
  ]
```

Now if we look at the generated text we can see `"Last"` is wholly absent from the first but present in the second:

```
testForm@FormPage[{"First" -> "String", 
    "Last" -> <|"Interpreter" -> "String", "Input" -> "Jones", 
      "Hidden" -> True|>}, # &] // StringContainsQ["Last"]

False

testForm@FormPage[{"Name:" -> 
     CompoundElement[<|"First" -> "String", 
       "Last" -> <|"Interpreter" -> "String", "Input" -> "Jones", 
         "Hidden" -> True|>|>]}, # &] // StringContainsQ["Last"]

True
```

This suggests it's just a bug with the processing of `CompoundElement`. I'd report it.

The only real workarounds will be hacks, since you'd need to trick the HTML exporter into adding styles to your elements to hide them with CSS or find a way .

Even using that export trick I used as a pre-processor step and then adding the HTML in post-processing doesn't seem to work, as the static HTML pages generated appear to not support the callback properly.

If you want to figure out exactly how to edit your `FormPage` to work I'd suggest looking into `` Templating`PackageScope`toHTMLNode `` as it's the apparent work-horse for these export processes.

Comment: Thanks @b3m2a1.  Using your function, I dug a bit more into the HTML being exported and you are absolutely right -- things are being processed much differently.  Not sure how much I want to go digging under the hood to fix a relatively minor problem, but as I build more complicated forms, that may need to the route I go.